# Trouble traversing XML file nodes

Tags: php, xml, foreach, tree, nodes

I have properly parsed one XML feed, and have inputted that data into a table on my site. However, I am dealing with a slightly more complicated feed, and am having trouble finding tree nodes.

XML Feed: http://xml.pinnaclesports.com/pinnaclefeed.aspx?sporttype=Football&sportsubtype=NFL

Declare variables:

```
$AwayLine = (string)$xml2->spread_visiting;  
$HomeLine = (string)$xml2->home_visiting;
```

From my understanding, the feed is broken down as(obviously, im wrong):

```
foreach ($xml2->event->period[0]->spread as $Spread) {  
    $AwayLine = $Spread->spread_visiting;   
    $HomeLine = $Spread->spread_home;  
}
```

Based on the XML path, every item is seen as an event. Every event has multiple periods. Every period has a spread. Every spread includes spread_visiting and spread_home. However, I only need the spreads in the first period, or period[0]

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: just a quick question with pinnacle sports api, the XML feed only returns the results of the coming fixtures, how do you get the results of the games?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both `events` and `periods` are missing from your statement, so it should be:

```
foreach ($xml2->events->event as $event) {
    foreach ($event->periods->period[0]->spread as $spread) {
    }
}
```

Not 100% sure about it, but you might be able to write this as well:

```
foreach ($xml2->events->event->periods->period[0]->spread as $spread) { }
```

Comment: I tried the above code and was getting NULL values on my var_dump. Do you know if I initialized my variables correctly? I have class, but I'll try more configurations when I get out. Thanks for the reply @Jack!